# Why am I not able to return any python code?

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, anaconda

I'm a new programmer trying to learn python and I am running into some issues. I install the latest version of Python 3 on my M1 MacBook Air recently and the Python code not returning anything - not in Pycharm, VScode, Jupyter, or Spider

In all the Anaconda apps, I keep getting the same issue for some libraries,  ‘module not found’

In PyCharm, the IDE cannot find and read my excel docs that I want to automate

I think the issue is that I downloaded too many versions of python. First, I downloaded python then PyCharm. Then I downloaded Anaconda.
And I think the libraries now don’t know where to look so they don’t return anything.

Not sure how to fix this?

Comment: (Personally), I’d probably start over and just install Anaconda and dump off PyCharm (opinion: it’s bloated) and use Spyder.

Comment: Which libraries does not work?

Comment: @ph140 pandas and openpyxl. when I checked in the terminal using pip install it stated they were already satisfied

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all of this and then only install Anaconda.

Then, using Anaconda navigator, you can install Pycharm and all the libraries you need.

More information about Anaconda navigator here : https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/

Comment: What are you trying to run. Can you post sample code

Comment: I am trying to do 2 things: 1) automate excel 2) do Monte Carlo simulations Pycharm code: import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.load_workbook('meta.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
cell = sheet['a1']
print(cell.value)

Comment: code in jypter: import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt